# 2D Numpy Array Fancy Indexing + Masking

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, array-broadcasting

I have:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[ 4, 99,  2],
              [ 3,  4, 99],
              [ 1,  8,  7],
              [ 8,  6,  8]])
```

Why is

```
a[[True, True, False, False], [1,2]]
```

Equal to

```
array([99, 99])
```

And not

```
array([99, 2],
      [4, 99])
```

Since I am selecting the first two rows using a boolean mask and the 2nd and 3rd columns using fancy indexing? Especially since calling

```
a[[True, True, False, False],:][:, [1,2]]
```

gives me my expected result. Im guessing its some sort of broadcasting rule but it isn't apparent to me. Thanks!

Comment: I get a `IndexError: shape mismatch: indexing arrays could not be broadcast together with shapes (4,) (2,)` for your query...

Comment: That's just subscripted indexing, selecting one element each from the group of indices taken from each index at each dim. So, its indexing with `(0,1)` [0 from the boolean array's first TRUE elem, 1 from the int indexing array's first elem] for the first elem and `(1,2)` for the second.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I think OP meant using boolean **array** not just a plain python list for indexing. If you cast them into arrays, then you'll get OP's result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A boolean array or list evaluates as though `where` had converted it to an index array:

```
In [285]: a[[True,True,False,False],[1,2]]
Out[285]: array([99, 99])

In [286]: a[np.where([True,True,False,False]),[1,2]]
Out[286]: array([[99, 99]])

In [287]: np.where([True,True,False,False])
Out[287]: (array([0, 1], dtype=int32),)

In [288]: a[[0,1], [1,2]]
Out[288]: array([99, 99])
```

So this is picking `a[0,1]` and `a[1,2]`, a 'pair-wise' selection.

The block is indexed with arrays (or list equivalents) that broadcast against each other to produce a (2,2) array:

```
In [289]: a[np.ix_([0,1], [1,2])]
Out[289]: 
array([[99,  2],
       [ 4, 99]])
In [290]: a[[[0],[1]], [1,2]]
Out[290]: 
array([[99,  2],
       [ 4, 99]])
```

This case is equivalent to a 2 stage indexing: `a[[0,1],:][:,[1,2]]`

I'm using np version 12.  There have been some changes in boolean index over the recent releases.  For example, if the length of the boolean isn't right, it runs, but gives a warning (this part is new).

```
In [349]: a[[True,True,False],[1,2]]
/usr/local/bin/ipython3:1: VisibleDeprecationWarning: boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension 0; dimension is 4 but corresponding boolean dimension is 3
  #!/usr/bin/python3
Out[349]: array([99, 99])
```

Changes for v 13 are described in:

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/release.html#boolean-indexing-changes

Comment: how come you don't get `IndexError` by just using the plain python list for indexing?

Comment: I'm using np.version: 1.12.0.  There's been a change in how boolean indexing is handled.

Comment: @hpaulj If a[ [ True,True,False,False ], [ 1,2 ] ] comes down to:
a[ [ 0,1 ], [1,2 ] ]
Then, a[ 0:2, [1,2] ] is different from previous. Because a[ 0:2, [1,2] ] will select subset matrix.

Answer (score 1):

I think it works like the following:

```
In [284]: a
Out[284]: 
array([[ 4, 99,  2],
       [ 3,  4, 99],
       [ 1,  8,  7],
       [ 8,  6,  8]])

In [286]: bo
Out[286]: array([ True,  True, False, False], dtype=bool)

In [287]: boc
Out[287]: array([1, 2])
```

Now, once we index `a` with the boolean mask `bo`, we get:

```
In [285]: a[bo]
Out[285]: 
array([[ 4, 99,  2],
       [ 3,  4, 99]])
```

Since, `bo` evaluates to `[1, 1, 0, 0]`, this will just select first two rows of `a`.

Now, we apply `boc` i.e. `[1, 2]` *in combination* with the row selecting mask `bo`.

```
In [288]: a[bo, boc]
Out[288]: array([99, 99])
```

Here, the mask `boc` is applied to the **already fetched rows**. And it selects second element from first row, third element from second row yielding `[99, 99]`.

But, interestingly if you do something like:

```
In [289]: a[1, [1, 2]]
Out[289]: array([ 4, 99])
```

In this case, numpy broadcasts yielding the indices `[(1,1), (1,2)]`