# Visible deprecation error message

Tags: python, numpy

While running python for one variable I got the following error , python stopped and output file was not created

> VisibleDeprecationWarning: boolean index did not match indexed array
>   along dimension 0; dimension is 4 but corresponding boolean dimension
>   is 2

The following is the part of code where its showing the error

```
cons = ({'type':'ineq',
'fun': lambda x: x[:num_products]},{'type':'ineq',
'fun': lambda x: np.array(np.sum(rho_L04.dot(x[:num_products])) -np.sum(S_L04[:,store_count]))},{'type':'eq',
'fun': lambda x: x[S_L04[:,store_count]==0]})
```

So can anyone help me how to fix this?

Comment: The warning actually won't stop the code execution as it is just a warning. However, your example is not complete. By just copy and pasting it the warning is not visible.

Comment: I would check the shape of `x`, `S_L04` and `store_count`.

Comment: I explain this warning in http://stackoverflow.com/a/42863250/901925.  It's up to you to identify where the boolean indexing is occuring.